# I just need some advice or assistance if possible? I'd really appreciate anyones 2cents on this

Tags: client, bitcoin-core-development, buy-bitcoins

I sent BTC from Paxful to an exchange called LAtoken. $36 worth of BTC was sent, nothing major to anyone else but really huge to me. Cope pasted and confirmed address. NO btc arrived almost a day later.
When I check on the blockchain the address says

"This address has transacted 2 times on the Bitcoin blockchain. It has received a total of 0.00022816 BTC ($13.04) and has sent a total of 0.00022816 BTC ($13.04). The current value of this address is 0.00000000 BTC ($0.00)."

The exchange is not answering as well so I'm lost. So frustrated and wondering if the money is lost. I would love to just be sure.

here is the Txhash

9875516de2037143c60ae2bb84d3cf18678c0c906a9c712eddd36e65018f5d6f

here is the address

1J4TJDRuCvTJ9hCL7cXihtAZbM3THVKC6d

Answer (score 1):

This is from [LAtoken faq](https://latoken.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018713832-I-can-t-see-my-deposit):

> **I can't see my deposit**
>
> If you have made a deposit to your LATOKEN account, but the amount is not
> reflected in your balance, it might be caused by one of the following:
>
> 1. Deposit was below minimum deposit, please refer to min amount on
>    deposit screen. In this case, deposits are considered unrecoverable.
> 2. Deposit has wrong/missing memo - create a ticket and tell us the
>    correct memo, we will deposit it manually (may take up to 1 week).
> 3. Deposit was not yet processed on the blockchain. Here are the
>    approximate time frames after which you should create a ticket:
>
>    - ~30 minutes for ETH, ERC-20, NEO;
>    - ~1.5 hours for BTC;
>    - ~3 hours for NIMIQ, Mircoin;
>    - ~30 days for BAYR.

My guess is that your deposit is below minimum deposit but I don't have an account there and can't check; if not, you can send the transaction ID to their support following the link above and ask them to verify.

Comment: Thanks, my deposit was above their min deposit. They require 0.0005 btc, I deposited 0.00062816 to the address. Either way its looking like they scammed me.

Comment: The transaction of which you provide the ID has an amount of 0.00022816 as you stated in the question. If you send the amount you want deposit with multiple transaction, the minimum amount is applied on every single transaction.

Comment: That's what I don't seem to get. The address they gave me is what I copy pasted to exactly on Paxful. I sent it all fully once. Once it got to the blockchain I don't understand how it was split in two. I have no clue what happens with btc on the blockchain, could you please explain if possible?

Comment: I don't have any info on the other transaction you talk about. If you have inserted this addr: 1J4TJDRuCvTJ9hCL7cXihtAZbM3THVKC6d to withdraw from paxful, the mistake is theirs: the blockchain certify  that they sent only 0.00022816. That said, i notice that difference from the amount you wanted to transfer and actual transferred is exactly 0.0004 btc, maybe there is a withdrawal fee on paxful that you did not take into account?